# Best way to debug from Google Chrome console the .js file if it is loaded and executed AFTER button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, console

Let's say the page http://www.example.com  is opened in my browser. I click on the button `button1` on that page that triggers

```
$('.popup').load(popupContentURL);
```

to be executed.
The new content is displayed in the popup. Everything is perfect.
The question is: the page `popupContentURL` has such a code inside:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspopup.js"></script>
```

As result, when you click on the button `button1`, the javascript code from `jspopup.js` is being loaded and executed.

My question is: is there any way to debug `jspopup.js` from the Chrome console?
I wish to start debugging from the very first line.
The problem is that when I'm on the http://www.example.com and on the way to click the "button1" button, I can NOT set up a breakpoint inside the `jspopup.js` as it is not loaded yet.

**All that files are not local. They are located at http://www.example.com .**

Comment: Yes, you can. SourceURLs will be your friend: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-dynamic-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can very well do that .  The Chrome DevTools include a number of useful tools to help make debugging JavaScript less painful. [Check here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know how to debug, but my question was about the problem that I can't set up a breakpoint inside the javascript file that is not loaded yet. Could you please explain how to go through jspopup.js line by line? I'm sure I'm missing something. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't but try breakpoint.js define beforehand your breakpoints hope that helps url:http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome you can use the `debugger;` statement within your loaded code.

If you have the Chrome F12 developer console open it will break at that line so you can debug from that point onwards.

Lots of other useful tips here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: I can NOT modify that files. All URLs are not local.

Comment: In your example it was local, but there are plenty of other options on that linked Chrome debugging page (which I see two others have also provided).

Comment: and never say never (or *cannot*)... As it is just for debugging, you can always copy the external file local and change the code :)

Comment: That's right, my question was if it is possible to test it without creating all that staff (to test it locally, I need to set up a jQuery popup library, and so on which takes more that 1 minute)...